# Assigning Variable name as function parameter java

Tags: java, operating-system

I want to make new variable

> String x = new String();

Note that I want "x" to be replaced with a function parameter as follows -->

```
void function(String desiredName){
     String desiredName = "bbb";
}
```

To make it simple I just need to make a variable with the same name of a function input.

Comment: You stopped just before telling us why you want to do this... and we think you're probably asking how to design the wrong solution. Please share your problem and you'll get relevant answers.

Comment: I have a project in the operating systems course which asks us to read the instruction file and execute it in the desired way.
one of the instructions is 'assign a b' ,
which means that we need to make a string a hold value of b that's it.

Comment: Do you mean that I make all variables hashmap and put in it what is assigned?

Comment: But how can I make it accepts <string,string> and <string,int> ?

Comment: Okay, I've got the point I will make my research thank you so much for your effort.